# Intercom API (v2.0) search conversation not working

Tags: postman, intercom

I tried to search conversation from Intercom API using Postman but it always return server error message.
I just followed their API [docs](https://developers.intercom.com/intercom-api-reference/v0/reference#search-for-conversations).

request url: POST https://api.intercom.io/conversations/search?query=updated_at>1590278400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should be in JSON format in the **Body**, not in the **querystring** like you do in your example:

```
{
 "query":  {
    "field": "updated_at",
    "operator": ">",
    "value": 1590278400
  }
}
```

In Postman it looks like this (note: don't forget to add your authentication)

[image]

Comment: I tried your answer but now it returns a new error `{
    "type": "error.list",
    "request_id": "000scp4srbu9aphrf3q0",
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "invalid_query",
            "message": "Query body must contain a query hash"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: To fix my new issue I just changed my body format to JSON